# Weird behaviour when using the modulo operator between a negative int and std::size_t

Tags: c++, modulo

This code snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    int a{-4}; 
    std::size_t b{3};
    std::cout << a % b;

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
0
```

while this code snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a{-4}; 
    int b{3};
    std::cout << a % b;

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
-1
```

So, why does the first code snippet returns `0`? Why does changing `b` from `std::size_t` to `int` print the right result?

Comment: Simple rule, don't mix types. And if you mix types: do cast explicitly to what you want the code to do. Do you want module of two ints or modulo of two size_t variables? Be explicit

Comment: Strangely similar question (also uses `-4` and `3`) posted about half an hour before this one: [Why is leetcode modulo operator of negative numbers = 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70061571/why-is-leetcode-modulo-operator-of-negative-numbers-0)

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, that's because I see the question, and got confused myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, it's because `a` implicitly converted into `std::size_t` becuase `b` is `std::size_t`, which is `4294967292`(on my machine), and `4294967292 % 3 == 0`

Comment: It is implicitly **converted**. There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.